# Best way to update a record using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to update in my tables using Entity Framework. But, I get an error.

My `EfRepositoryBase` class is implementing `IEntityRepository`. What is wrong with this method?

```
public bool UpdateWithProperty(TEntity entity, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] properties)
{
    using (var context = new TContext())
    {
        context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);

        var updatedEntity = context.Entry(entity);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
           updatedEntity.Property(property).IsModified = true;
        }

        updatedEntity.State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserName', table 'Nextt.dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

Comment: There's probably nothing wrong with it. You're trying to set a field to blank. I guess that the `UserName` attribute of the entity being passed in is blank. and that's not allowed in the database. You need to check the data being passed inat run time and confirm this. Your application should have logic which does not allow this to be blank in the first place

Comment: The exception is self-explanatory: EF tried to update "UserName" field with null value while the column in DB set to "NOT NULL". You need to examine passed data which possible containing null value and put a check against null on it (e.g. with `if` block).

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
    db.context.Attach(obj);
    DbEntityEntry entry = db.Entry(obj);
    foreach (var proprty in entry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
    {
        if(entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(proprty) != null)
            if (!object.Equals(entry.GetDatabaseValues().GetValue<object>(proprty), entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(proprty)))
            {
                entry.Property(proprty).IsModified = true;
            }
    }

   db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: it's a different method.

Comment: Yeah that's obvious. Now how does it help?